# Javascript Add data to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the javascript code that ONCLICK retrieves text from another PHP file and Puts it in DIV. The main code works, but I need to ADD retrieved text to Div content. Instead of that, it´s replacing content of DIV with retrieved text.

```
  $.post("getdata/some.php",{partialStates:option.value},function(data){
  $("#some").html(data);
```

Div id=some

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `append()` or retrieve the html first, add your data, then set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the jquery append method

```
$('#some').append(data);
```

instead of

```
$('#some').html(data);
```